# PostgreSQL prevent subquery inlining using OFFSET 0

Tags: postgresql, indexing, subquery, inlining

I have a sub-query in where clause which scans full table each time it is evaluated.

```
SELECT k, j
FROM tab t1     
WHERE t1.x > (SELECT AVERAGE(x) FROM tab t2 where t1.n = t2.n)
order by k, j 
limit 100;
```

There is no change in query plan when I add OFFSET 0 to the end of the subquery.

```
SELECT k, j
FROM tab t1     
WHERE t1.x > (SELECT AVERAGE(x) FROM tab t2 where t1.n = t2.n OFFSET 0) 
order by k, j
limit 100;
```

Refering to this [post](http://blog.endpoint.com/2009/04/offset-0-ftw.html) . Will optimization fence, "OFFSET 0", not work in this case in where clause?

Comment: Show the `explain` or `explain analyze` when talking about query plans please. If you obfuscate/anonymize the query, make sure it exactly matches the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the average is calculated for a majority of the values of `n`, use a CTE for better performance:

```
WITH avg AS (
  SELECT n, average(x) FROM tab GROUP BY n
)
SELECT k, j
FROM tab
JOIN avg USING (n)    
WHERE x > average
ORDER BY k, j
LIMIT 100;
```